# apache mod rewrite folders hide

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want the URL **domain.com/folder/login.php**
rewritten to **domain.com/login** and managed to get .php "removed" but I am not able to get /folder/ removed I get a 500 or 404 error when trying to make a rule for the rewrite engine

this is my current rewrite rule :

```
<Directory />
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
AllowOverride None
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
</Directory>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right below `RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]` add:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+folder/
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/folder/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/folder/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1.php [L]
```

Not sure what that `/backend/` rule at the end is for, but it redirects, and you need all your redirect rules before your routing rules.